# Why does Hibernate (JPA) ignore FetchType.LAZY for ManyToOne relations?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-one

I have this entity for which I want a many-to one relation beeing loaded lazy.

```
@Entity
public class Product {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "atc_code_id")
    private ATCCode atcCode;
}

@Entity
public class ATCCode {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "atcCode")
    private Set<Product> products;
}
```

I'm using this code to load products:

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select p from Product as p");
List<Product> products = q.getResultList();
```

From the second last line in the hibernate log I can see that a second select is issued to initialize the proxoy for atcCode. Why?

```
17925 07 Aug 2015 11:45:20 SQL DEBUG 352066 kb - select product0_.id ...
17926 07 Aug 2015 11:45:20 Loader DEBUG 348515 kb - Result set row: 0
17927 07 Aug 2015 11:45:20 Loader DEBUG 348515 kb - Result row: EntityKey[com.galexis.search.importer.search.searchdb.model.Product#1]
17928 07 Aug 2015 11:45:20 Loader DEBUG 348515 kb - Result set row: 1
17929 07 Aug 2015 11:45:20 Loader DEBUG 348515 kb - Result row: EntityKey[com.galexis.search.importer.search.searchdb.model.Product#2]
17929 07 Aug 2015 11:45:20 TwoPhaseLoad DEBUG 348515 kb - Resolving associations for [com.galexis.search.importer.search.searchdb.model.Product#1]
17931 07 Aug 2015 11:45:20 TwoPhaseLoad DEBUG 348515 kb - Done materializing entity [com.galexis.search.importer.search.searchdb.model.Product#1]
17931 07 Aug 2015 11:45:20 TwoPhaseLoad DEBUG 348515 kb - Resolving associations for [com.galexis.search.importer.search.searchdb.model.Product#2]
17931 07 Aug 2015 11:45:20 TwoPhaseLoad DEBUG 348515 kb - Done materializing entity [com.galexis.search.importer.search.searchdb.model.Product#2]
17931 07 Aug 2015 11:45:20 SessionImpl DEBUG 348515 kb - Initializing proxy: [com.galexis.search.importer.search.searchdb.model.ATCCode#100]
17931 07 Aug 2015 11:45:20 SQL DEBUG 348515 kb - select atccode0_.id  ...
```

My expectation would be that a proxy for atcCode is returned. As long I don't access atcCode, it should not be loaded from the DB.

Any ideas why hibernate initializes the proxy?

This is stripped down explanation of the problem. In reality I have lots of many-to-one relations on product. All of them are declared lazy. But since they are actually loaded egarly, I get a big select N+1 performance penalty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching I ended up setting a break point in `org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl` where the log statement `Initializing proxy:` is generated. Going up the stack trace I finally found this in `Product`:

```
@PostLoad
public void postLoad() {
    atcCode.getCode();
}
```

This causes hibernate to initialize the proxy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? You´re still trying to get lazy loading working, don´t you?

Comment: It perfectly answers the question. The postLoad renders the lazy loading decleration useless since it forces hibernate to initialize the proxy.

Comment: ok... I just thought you might wanted to know how you can suppress that call.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this answer is a fairly edge-case minority one for those who are seeing this issue.

Comment: I am facing same problem, how can i supress the call?